# Forward a mail using Tmail & ActionMailer::ARMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tmail, ar-mailer

I'm writing a rake task to go through one of our mailboxes of incoming mail, using Tmail.  For certain mails, i just want to forward them on to another address.  I'm not sure what the best way to do that is though.

Our regular mails for the website are sent out using ARMailer: i call Mailer.deliver_ and the mail is generated from a template and put into our Email table, which in accessed by ARMailer which actually sends the mails out.  So, the class definition of my Mailer class looks like this:

```
class Mailer < ActionMailer::ARMailer
  #list of methods here, one per email type
end
```

So, what i want to do, is, in my script when i have a Tmail object representing the incoming mail, is to generate a new mail to stick into our mail queue which is basically the Tmail mail, forwarded onto a new address.  I'm not sure what the best way to do that is.  I could build up a new multipart mail copying the body, subject and from field from the recieved Tmail object, but that seems like it might be a bit clumsy, and that there should be a nicer way.

Can i do something like

newmail = Mailer.create_forward(my_tmail_object)
newmail.to = "forwardingaddress@domain.com"
newmail.deliver

??

Mailer/ARMailer doesn't have the create_forward method but it's something like that that i'm after.  Any advice welcome!  thanks